# How do I prime MySQL so I can benchmark the performance of my query / index?

Tags: mysql, caching, indexing, buffer

I have a 25 million row MySQL 5.6 table. I'm in the process of refining my indexes on the table. When I execute a simple query the first time it takes 10 seconds and it only takes 0.1 seconds every subsequent time. When I filter on a different key the execution time jumps back up to 10 seconds.

This behavior tells me I'm reaping the benefits of caching and buffering on the subsequent queries. I understand MySQL implements an `QUERY CACHE` but subsequent queries post `RESET QUERY CACHE` still only take 0.1 seconds.

I would ideally like to:

- Call the query a few times to get a baseline average execution time (i.e. 10.38 seconds over 10 instance).
- Refine my table index design
- Call the query a few times to get a new average execution time (i.e. 7.91 seconds over 10 instance).
- Decide whether to keep or discard the refinements

How do I prime MySQL so I can benchmark the performance of my query / index without the benefit of the buffering, caching, pre-fetching, etc?

Comment: Don't forget that OS file caches and hardware caches will have a profound impact on performance. http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/09/12/query-profiling-with-mysql-bypassing-caches/

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a `performance_schema` named database default. It can be usefull for you. If it not exists on your server try to turn on this feature. Here's a description: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html

Answer (score 1):

Executive summary:

- Turn off the Query cache;
- Set innodb_buffer_pool_size;
- Run your test query twice, using the second timing;
- Don't try to include all the I/O; it's not realistic.

Details:

First, you need to understand what the "Query cache" is and is not.  It is a kludge that is usually best turned off.  It records the exact queries (byte for byte) and their result sets, but it gets purged whenever a write occurs.  (I am over-simplifying it.)  So, either turn it off, or use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to keep it from confusing the benchmarks.  A typical query that can make use of the QC will take about 1 millisecond, regardless of how complex it is.  That's *not* a useful metric.

Now, let's get to the 'real' cache -- InnoDB's "buffer pool".  (I assume you are using InnoDB, not MyISAM.)  That cache should be about 70% of available RAM (but may not be if you have not set innodb_buffer_pool_size in my.cnf).  It caches reads and writes for the *blocks* that make up InnoDB tables.  When you read a record from a table, InnoDB needs to find some block(s) from the index you are using, plus the block(s) that contain the data.  Reading a block from disk takes, say, 10ms.  If these were recently looked at, then they are very likely to be in the buffer pool.  Usually the difference is 10x between not cached and cached.  (You are seeing a 100x speedup, so I may not be explaining everything.)

When testing the speed of a given query, I like to run it twice.  The first time it will fetch any blocks not yet in the buffer pool, then it will use just CPU effort to perform it.  The second run will be only CPU (unless it, say, scans 25M rows and they don't fit in the buffer pool).

To get timings for I/O gets more complex, and often not necessary.  I say "not necessary" because comparing two runs that show a difference in CPU time generally implies that the I/O could also be similarly different.  Also, timing I/O is not realistic because in "production" the buffer pool is full of stuff cached, hence many queries won't need to hit the disk.

If you would like to discuss your app further, we can discuss PARTITIONing (not necessarily beneficial), Data Warehousing (and speed techniques), and/or UUIDs (bad), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SQL_NO_CACHE function in order to disable the MySQL query cache on a per-query basis

```
 SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE <columns> FROM table WHERE <condition>;
```

One thing you have to use is the EXPLAIN command in order to know which indices are used in your query, or aren't:

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE <columns> FROM table WHERE <condition>;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has more powerful ways to judge query performance, the timing helps, but explain provides more insight (I believe it forces the query to run uncached, since other databases do this for execution numbers, but I can't find a reference).

If you make index changes to the database, you're going to first want to optimize for the index.  This updates the statistics tables to tell MySQL how to build your explain plan.  The syntax is just:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE_NAME
```

Plus some light reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Then you're going to want to run an explain plan to tell you what MySQL is really doing with your indices.  If you put on indices that never get used, then you're just slowing down your inserts. How to run:

```
EXPLAIN YOUR_QUERY
```

Here's an example from MySQL

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED
-> SELECT t1.a, t1.a IN (SELECT t2.a FROM t2) FROM t1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: t1
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
        table: t2
         type: index_subquery
possible_keys: a
          key: a
      key_len: 5
          ref: func
         rows: 2
        Extra: Using index
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Level: Note
   Code: 1003
Message: select `test`.`t1`.`a` AS `a`,
         <in_optimizer>(`test`.`t1`.`a`,
         <exists>(<index_lookup>(<cache>(`test`.`t1`.`a`)
         in t2 on a checking NULL having
         <is_not_null_test>(`test`.`t2`.`a`)))) AS `t1.a
         IN (SELECT t2.a FROM t2)` from `test`.`t1`
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice the rows field, this tells you how many records MySQL had to deal with to get your answer.  Since this involves an inner select, then the "query cost" should be ~4+2, which is a relative number you can compare against a different query.  Whereas, if it were a join then the "query cost" would be ~4x2.  You can consider the type a modifier to your cost equation, but it's easiest just to go with the best possible type for whatever operation you're doing.  There's a pretty good explanation about types on the blog post link below.

More explain plan reading: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

A pretty good explain plan explanation: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

Answer (score 1):

What you experience is the difference between a hot and a cold query / database. A hot query is a query accessing the required data already being in memory where a cold (query) needs to load its data into the memory. Thats why with big databases you speak of a warmup phase before the data cache in the memory contains the data necessary for serving most of the requests.

Sure it can be the query cache but is also likely its more likely the disk cache. Depends on the memory you are using.

Next question is what are you going to do with your database. Usually today you are highly likely to through memory at the problem. A TB of memory just cost 10k. So who cares.

Also use explain. Database is usually all about pages you page in from the database and the way the inmemory data is used to fullfill your request.

EXPLAIN is the correct way to use. Query Cache you can usually switch off. Not much use to it. If the result is static it is highly likely you use a web cache or site cache for that anyways.

Also check the indizes being used. Often you find ways to ease the pain.

Answer (score 1):

when I was doing this, I used `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE`.

Or you can make whitespace changes to the query each time.  The query cache indexes by the verbatim query string, and any change, including extra spaces, appear to be a different query.